# d3 make Y axis position fixed even the scroller x

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart with alot of data that means I have a scroller over the x axis.
when I scroll over the X axis Y axis disappear.

can i set to Y axis position fixed. ( always see this Y axis)?

https://jsfiddle.net/ou28se1z/1/
I tried to add   `.attr("position", "fixed")` but it doesnt work

```
//Add Y axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
.attr("position", "fixed")
.call(yAxis);
```

I also tried to do .style("position", "fixed")

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
.style("position", "fixed")
.call(yAxis);
```

but its not work

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/brantwills/pen/igsoc

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);    

function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);   
    svg.selectAll('path.line').attr('d', line);  

    points.selectAll('circle').attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
    ); 
}
```